# Javascript if statement not being executed inside a function - global variable issue?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, global-variables

I am creating a browser-based Blackjack game as a project for a coding bootcamp. I have set the following global variable:

```
let playerScore = 0
```

I have an array of objects that hold a key called 'value', e.g.:

```
const cards = [
    {name: '2Hearts', value: 2, suit: 'hearts', cardClass: 'number'},
    {name: '3Hearts', value: 3, suit: 'hearts', cardClass: 'number'},
```

Upon dealing the cards, these are pushed to a new array of objects called "cardsDealtToPlayer". I then calculate the sum of the 'value' values with this function:

```
function sumCardsDealtToPlayer() {
    var cardsDealtToPlayerTotal = cardsDealtToPlayer.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return {
      value: previousValue.value + currentValue.value
    }
})
playerScore = cardsDealtToPlayerTotal
}
```

I have tested through the console and see that the `playerScore = …` line of code assigns the sum of `value` values to the playerScore global variable successfully after being invoked.

However, when I invoke the following function (and the playerScore value is over 21), the if statement does not execute.

I have used console log to confirm that playerScore is being read inside the function (before the if), but that it is not being read the playerScore variable - it seems as if the if statement is not being executed, but I don't know why!!!

```
function checkPlayerScore() {
    console.log(playerScore) // playerScore is being read here
    if (playerScore > 21) {
        console.log(playerScore) // playerScore is not being read here
        console.log("Player is Bust!")
        renderMessage("Player is Bust!")
        winner = "dealer"
        phase = "end"
        return
    } 
}
```

For reference, the functions are invoked through the following function to draw the first two cards for both player and dealer, and are successfully being pushed to the relevant new arrays. The if statement is just not being read in the checkPlayerScore function:

```
function startClick() {
    init()
    randomCardDraw()
    randomCardDraw()
    sumCardsDealtToDealer()
    checkDealerScore() // Also not working
    changeTurn()
    randomCardDraw()
    randomCardDraw()
    sumCardsDealtToPlayer()
    checkPlayerScore() // Not working
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you immensely in advance...

I am trying to use a global variable within an if statement inside of a function but it is not being read...help!!

I'm sure I'm being thick, but been working on it for hours and can't find any posts/responses that apply. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbd9X.png)Solved!

The playerScore being returned in the `sumCardsDealtToPlayer` function was returning an object - see image.

Resolved by simply adding a .value to the end of the `cardsDealtToPlayerTotal`, see below:

```
playerScore = cardsDealtToPlayerTotal.value
```

Comment: pls make sure functions/variables or anything related to code should be in preper format wrt stackoverflow guidelines